# How to write a Helper class to map classes to each other in Java?

Tags: java, class

There is a question on my mind for a while. Let's say we have the following classes:

```
public Class Person{
    String name;
    String address;
    String description;
}

public Class PersonFacade{
    String name;
    String address;
    String desc;
}
```

as you can see the only difference between these two classes are the name of one variable. My question is what is the best way to write a helper class to map the values of one object to another object. Let's assume we have the following:

```
Person person = new Person();
person.name="name1";
person.address="address1";
person.description="description1";
```

I want to write a class that is supposed to do the following (let's call it Transformer class)

```
PersonFacade personFacade = new PersonFacade();
TransformClass.transformFrom(person, personFacade);
```

What I want this `TransformClass.transformFrom()` method to do is the follwoing:

based on the similarity of the variable names, assign the value of the variable from "FromClass" to "ToClass"
so in our case, I want it to assign `personFacade.name = "name1"`, `personFacade.address="adderss1"` and `personFacade.desc = "description1"` (this last one seems harder to accomplish, but let's try)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **Dozer**:

> Dozer is a Java Bean to Java Bean mapper that recursively copies data
>   from one object to another. Typically, these Java Beans will be of
>   different complex types.
>
> Dozer supports simple property mapping, complex type mapping,
>   bi-directional mapping, implicit-explicit mapping, as well as
>   recursive mapping. This includes mapping collection attributes that
>   also need mapping at the element level.

Look at this: http://dozer.sourceforge.net/

It's a great JavaBean Mapper.

Here the "Getting Started":

http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/gettingstarted.html

Comment: exactly what I was looking for, tnx

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can write your own [Annotation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/annotations.html) class in order to create the relationship between the classes.  So, for example

```
public Class Person{
    @MyAnnotation(id='name')
    String name;

    @MyAnnotation(id='addr')
    String address;

    @MyAnnotation(id='desc')
    String description;
}

public Class PersonFacade{
    @MyAnnotation(id='name')
    String name;

    @MyAnnotation(id='addr')
    String address;

    @MyAnnotation(id='desc')
    String desc;
}
```

Then in your TransformClass, you simply need to iterate through the annotations, find a match and set the corresponding field value with the help of [Reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/package-summary.html).